# How to inject mock dependencies into GWT rpc service implementation using GWTTestCase

Tags: gwt, junit

I want to unit-test my gwt-rpc interaction against my real rpc endpoint `HelloServiceImpl`. This service implementation has some dependencies to do its work. I use the junit GWTTestCase, and a test-scope module gwt.xml specification:

```
<module>
    <inherits name='...' />
    <servlet path="/HelloService/helloService.rpc" class="my.package.HelloServiceImpl" />
</module>
```

It is unclear to me how to control the instantiation of the service. I see that GWTTestCase indirectly invokes the default constructor of `HelloServiceImpl`. The question is: how do I inject the mock dependencies during or after instatiotion of the `HelloServiceImpl`?

Comment: Maybe it would be simplet if you tested your server and client components in isolation? You could use a tool like Jukito to auto-mock dependencies of your HelloServiceImpl, and run unit tests on HelloServiceImpl. You could use Mockito to verify that your RPC method is correctly invoked on the client side.